# I have an answer to a question, but maybe too many questions: should I post it?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I have an answer to a question, but maybe too many questions: should I post it as an answer?

I suddenly feel like I can make sense of some important Buddhist teachings, without resorting to technical vocabulary.

Comment: Good for you! Does "too many questions" mean that it's an answer to too many questions (so you don't know which question to post the answer), or that the answer includes a lot of unanswered question? Might you post it here if you want to discuss it, before deciding how or whether to post it on the main site?

Comment: the former, i wondered if that would make any answer seem like i was pushing a personal interpretation, though @ChrisW

Comment: if it seems too personal then someone let me know and i'll delete it @ChrisW https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/mahayana-specific-definition-of-a-buddha/35461#35461 thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it answers a question then post it as an answer to that question.

Please don't post the same answer to many questions -- different questions generally deserve different answers, one answer should be posted only once. If two questions are so similar that you think they deserve the same answer, then instead of posting the answer twice, answer only one question, and add a comment under the second to write, "See also [hyperlink to the related topic]".

A "personal interpretation" might be OK. In theory a "good answer" is "based on" something, the basis being either "a reference", or "personal experience" (which is sometimes defined as "something which happened to you personally").

Comment: ha, no i wasn't going to fo that!